# How to modify event that occurs when a laptop is closed?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, suspend, kde, laptop

I have Acer Aspire laptop with Kubuntu 16.04 installed on it. (KDE dekstop).

Currently when I close laptop it goes into weird suspend mode. It is not possible to wake it up. Only way is to force reset.

I am looking for any way to modify event that occurs when a laptop is closed. Either via GUI or terminal.

Answer (score 1):

There are two GUI ways to achieve the desired result.

#### Description

1. Per `Energy Saving` tab: `System Settings` > `Power Management` > `Energy Saving` > `On AC Power` (or another tab) > `Button Event Handling` > `When laptop lid closed`, and choose desired action.
2. Setting per KDE Activity: `System Settings` > `Power Management` > `Activity Settings` > *Your chosen Activity name*, choose radio-button `Use separate settings (advanced users only)` and select the desired action in `Button Event Handling` > `When laptop lid closed`.

I would like to use Activity settings, because it allows to add more flexibility (of course, if you use different KDE Activities for different tasks).

#### Screenshots

[image: Energy Saving tab]
<sup>**Energy Saving tab**</sup>

[image: Activity Settings]
<sup>**Activity settings**</sup>